# Is possible to set item params programmatically drawable xml file?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have drawable file that includes layer-list and items inside. I'm trying to set position of one item by variable (or method) from Java class.

I've tried to find it by id and use setLeft(int), but it doesn't work.

```java
findViewById(R.id.arr).setLeft(tone.position());
```

- tone.positions() gives me int values

```xml
<View
            android:id="@+id/vid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="90dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="90dp"
            android:background="@drawable/line"/>
```

This is in LinearLayout in MainActivity xml file

```xml
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#00ffffff"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:gravity="center">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:height="1dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#000000"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/arr"
        android:left="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:top="-5dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/arrow" />
</layer-list>
```

There is my drawable file. I want to change "left" attribute in item with "arr" id.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

`findViewById()` can be used to retrieve `View`s in your layout xml files. More specifically, the layout that you set using `setContentView()`. Your sample, will probably return null, since there is **no** `@+id/arr` in your layout. Hence, you can only use `findViewById()` to retrieve the view with `android:id="@+id/vid"`

You might be able to achieve what you want, by **first** getting the `View`. And getting the background from that view afterwards.

Something like this (untested):

```
val view = findViewById(R.id.vid)
val background = view.background as? LayerDrawable
background?.setLayerInsetLeft(R.id.arr, tone.positions())
```

or in Java (not sure about the syntax, but you'll get the idea):

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.vid);
LayerDrawable background = (LayerDrawable)(view.getBackground());
background.setLayerInsetLeft(R.id.arr, tone.positions());
```

For more details what you can do with a LayerDrawable, [look at the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable)

Comment: There's no errors in AndroidStudio but after run app in smartphone or virtual device app turns off. I've tried it for other drawables but it's same.

Comment: I tried also use index as int number 0-2 (I have 3 layers)  but app runs only when I use constant 2nd argument in setLayerInsetLeft method and I can't see different on screen.